# Using self-signed SSL certificate for deployment images

Tags: docker, ssl, kubernetes

I have private Docker registry which works over https with self-signed SSL certificate. I've installed this certificate on local machine and it's working fine (can push and pull).
Is it possible to configure Kubernetes to use this certificate for deployments (pull images from private registry)?

Comment: I am no sure if this is possible. But can't you use letsencrypt to generate a valid certificate?

Comment: @mbuechmann I will do it, if there is no way to configure it without buying custom domain, but I actually don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes it self doesn't support this. you have to deploy certificate to all worker nodes. You can simplify the process using [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) and [hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/)  volumes.